# can you have a encrypted hard drive on a mac? or is it just partial encryption?

Tags: hard-drive, security, encryption

not sure how this works, but can you have an entire hard drive encrypted and can it be your main hard drive with Mac Os/X on it or is it more of just for data only? i.e. other than base os files.

Comment: Similar question on apple.se: [What are my options for full system (or at least home directory) encryption?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/what-are-my-options-for-full-system-or-at-least-home-directory-encryption)

Answer (score 0):

PGP Whole Disk Encryption will work on OS X.

Comment: is it very slow on a laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. There are two options:

- [FileVault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileVault) is built into Mac OS X (since 10.3/Panther). At first you could only encrypt your home directory; since 10.7/Lion you can also encrypt the whole startup volume ([Inside Mac OS X 10.7 Lion: File Vault full disk encryption and cloud key storage](http://appleinsider.com/articles/11/02/28/inside_mac_os_x_10_7_lion_file_vault_full_disk_encryption_and_cloud_key_storage) ).
- PGP Whole Disk encryption supports OS X

Note: While TrueCrypt works on Mac OS X, it unfortunately does not support encrypting the system partition.